# How to list fields of current class in C# Reflection (problem with this.GetType())?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

This is accepted by the compiler:

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos;
fieldInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

This is NOT accepted by the compiler:

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos;
fieldInfos = typeof(this.GetType()).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

How to fix second syntax?

Comment: as indicated, `typeof` is only used when treating a type *symbol* as a `Type` object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `typeof()` around a `GetType` call since it already returns a Type object. `typeof` is a special syntax for getting a `Type` object from a type name, without having to do something like `Type.GetType("Foo")`.

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos;
fieldInfos = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                 BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` does not permit you to pass in an instance of `System.Type`. `typeof` is an operator whose sole parameter is a type (like `Int32`, or `object`, or `MyClass`) and it returns an instance of `System.Type`. When you already have an instance of an object, just call `GetType` so get an instance of `System.Type`. Therefore, just say

```
fieldInfos = this.GetType()
                 .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `typeof` in the second example. Just use:

```
 FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                   BindingFlags.Instance);
```

The point of `typeof` is it's a sort of "literal" format for obtaining a `Type` reference. `GetType()` already returns a type, so you don't need it.

To put it another way, suppose you wanted a string... you wouldn't use:

```
string x = "y.ToString()";
```

you'd just use

```
string x = y.ToString();
```

Replace the quotes with `typeof()` and it's the same sort of thing...

Comment: jon, leave the easy stuff to others, c'mon, go help the people at ddd9

Comment: @flq: No need for help - Mark Rendle's doing fabulously :)

Answer (score 2):

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```